# Fill Another Sheet Using Formula With Data From Another Sheet meeting Some Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is the description of what I'm trying to do in excel without using VBA:

Assume that you have some data as shown in the image below in `Sheet1`.

[Linke to Sheet1 image (Main Data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4f2B.png)

In Case link above is not working, here is the data in sheet1:

```
ProductionDate      ProductionLine    ProductCode    ProductName   ProductionQuantity  
1/5/2017            A                 805            AA            100  
1/5/2017            B                 912            BB            50  
13/6/17             A                 916            CC            250  
15/6/17             B                 805            AA            150  
23/6/17             B                 535            DD            50  
2/9/2017            B                 916            CC            200   
12/9/2017           A                 916            CC            200  
27/09/17            A                 805            AA            200
```

In Sheet2 I need to have the produced quantity of each product by the product line and also the total produced quantity of that item (the sum of produced quantity by all product lines). That means I need the result in sheet2 to be something like the image below.

[Link to Sheet2 Image (Result I'm Looking for)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hucTy.png)

In Case the link above is not working, here are the results I'm looking for in `Sheet2`:

```
ProductCode     ProductName     ProductionLine  ProducedQuantityByLine  TotalQuanity
535             DD              B               50                      50
805             AA              A               300                     450
805             AA              B               150                     450
912             BB              B               50                      50
916             CC              A               450                     650
916             CC              B               200                     650
```

I really need to know how to do this. I need some formulas to fill `Sheet2` automaticly for each product code in `Sheet1`. I can not enter `Productode` manually because the real number and range is huge (assume 1000 Product codes).

Comment: Your images are not coming through, and in any case it would be preferable to have text instead.

Comment: It should be possible to do this using a pivot table (taking ProdcutCode, ProductName and ProductLine as Row Labels). Probably Classic Layout. However, if I try that, I get the totals as rows, while you want them as Columns ...

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: I have edited my post and added the data in sheet 1 and sheet 2 as text also. Will try your solution as pivot table but I need the totals as columns like you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below, pasted in a module, should do what you require. Some notes and caveats apply though.

1. Code assumes two sheets named "Sheet1" and "Sheet2"
2. Code assumes the data to be processed to be in "Sheet1" and start in cell "A2"
3. Code assumes the results to be written to "Sheet2" and to start in "A2"
4. Code assumes the headers are already present in "Sheet2"
5. Code assumes there is no data in "Sheet2 other than the headers
6. Code assumes continuous data i.e. no empty rows or rows with empty cells (particularly in the ProductionDate column).
7. This code is very resource heavy as it continuously interacts with the sheets itself, this means that a large data set will take a long time. In my opinion a better solution, but in my opinion also a more complex solution, is to work with arrays. This way the code only reads and writes once.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub combineAndCopyData()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsResult As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim blnRecorded As Boolean, blnAdded As Boolean
    Dim lngTotal As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Substitute Sheet1 for the actual name of your sheet
    Set wsResult = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Subtitue Sheet2 for the actual name of your sheet

    For i = 2 To wsData.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        blnRecorded = False
        blnAdded = False
        For j = 1 To wsResult.Cells(wsResult.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            If wsData.Cells(i, 3) = wsResult.Cells(j, 1) And wsData.Cells(i, 2) = wsResult.Cells(j, 3) Then
                wsResult.Cells(j, 4) = wsResult.Cells(j, 4) + wsData.Cells(i, 5)
                blnRecorded = True
            End If
            If wsResult.Cells(j, 1) = Empty And Not blnRecorded Then
                wsResult.Cells(j, 1) = wsData.Cells(i, 3)
                wsResult.Cells(j, 2) = wsData.Cells(i, 4)
                wsResult.Cells(j, 3) = wsData.Cells(i, 2)
                wsResult.Cells(j, 4) = wsData.Cells(i, 5)
                wsResult.Cells(j, 5).Formula = "=SUMIF(A:A," & wsResult.Cells(j, 1).Address & ",D:D)" 'Keep in mind that Excel may require ";" or "," as argument separation.

            End If
        Next
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

### NOTE

In my original answer I noticed the TotalQuantity on Sheet2 not properly adding up. The code above has that issue corrected

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. It worked properly.